# Why one would use a symbol in attr_accessor and not a string?

Tags: ruby

So why would we do this in Ruby:

```
attr_accessor :price
```

Instead of:

```
attr_accessor 'price'
```

I have read that Symbols are similar to Strings, but they are immutable. But I fail to see why would we use that when doing attr_accessor, attr_reader. I mean, what are the advantages?

Comment: Symbols are immutable, but that's not the primary reason they're used. Symbols only have one instance; All occurrences of the same symbol point to the same spot in the variable space, so memory savings could be significant in a large application with a lot of instance variables.

Answer (score 3):

It's just the right thing to do. `Symbol` is a data type whose purpose is specifically to represent the concept of a "name" or "label". Here, you are using it to pass the name of a pair of methods to generate. `Symbol` is just the correct data type in this case. The methods also take `String`s for convenience reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Symbols are interned, unlike strings, so you avoid creating a ton of (potentially) duplicate string objects. Using the same `:foo` symbol in several places does not consume more memory at a constant rate, unless doing the same with `'foo'`

Comment: Usually, you don't need to use the same `:foo` symbol in several places.  When you use them, you make a call like `obj.foo`.

Comment: Although less likely to be the case with attr_accessor, etc. type metaprogramming, still can potentially happen, say somewhere else you do `obj.public_method(:foo)`.

Comment: That is irrelevant for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Preference. Symbols require less effort to type and some IDE's highlight them with pretty colors.

Comment: Also the [documentation specifies](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) that a symbol should be given.

Comment: @Jordan Much better answer.

Comment: Not only IDE, but also many other editors including vi. I think @Jordan nailed it.

Comment: How does a symbol take less effort? By reducing the key-count by one? That's not even worth considering. And IDE colors? Some IDEs and all the editors I use have pretty colors for strings too, but that's not a reason to use symbols with `attr_accessor`.